# Error when creating mysql function

Tags: mysql

```
  1 create function decipher_district_name(cust_code varchar(30))
  2 returns varchar(10)
  3 begin
  4   declare distcode varchar(10) default "hello";
  5   return distcode;
  6 end
  7 ;
```

Here is my code, I want to create a function but there are always error from line 4 near '',

I don't know how to fix it, please help me!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the delimiter before you define the function:

```
mysql>  delimiter //
```

Define your function like this (pay attention to the // at the end)

```
create function decipher_district_name(cust_code varchar(30))
returns varchar(10)
begin
  declare distcode varchar(10) default "hello";
  return distcode;
end
//
```

Change the delimiter back to `;`:

```
mysql> delimiter ;
```

Comment: Wow, you are awesome!

Comment: As I see, the error is because that MySQL cannot tell if it is the end of a clause or the end of the whole routine, right?